# How to check elements in a list WITHOUT using for loops?

Tags: python, list

Apologies if the title of the question is phrased badly. I am currently trying to make a function that takes in a list of integers from 1 to n, where n is the length of the list. The function should return the **first value** that is repeated in the list. Duplicates are NOT always next to one another. If one or more integers is less than 1 or if it is not a list, the function should return -1. If there are no duplicates, return 0.

This is my current code:

```
def find_duplicates(ls):
    if type(ls) != list:
        return -1

    non_dupe = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(ls):
        if ls[i] < 1:
            return -1
            break
        if ls.count(i) > 1:
            return i
            break
        else:
            non_dupe.append(i)
            i += 1

    if len(non_dupe) == len(ls):
        return 0
```

While this code works for a majority of test cases, it doesn't seem to pass

```
print(find_duplicates([1, 2, 2, 0]))
```

as it returns 2 instead of the expected -1. I am relatively new to Python and I can't seem to be able to fix this error. I've tried searching for ways to counter this problem but I am **not allowed** to use for loops to check through a list. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am **not** allowed to use any of the following but anything else is accepted.

1. for loops
2. min() / max()
3. enumerate() / zip ()
4. sort()
5. negative indexing e.g ls[-1]
6. list slicing

Comment: To check types keyword `is` is used. So, `if type(ls) is not list:`

Comment: @Goion Oh, thanks for letting me know. I'll fix that

Comment: @j1-lee Yes, I am not allowed to use for loops but I am allowed to use while. I will edit my post to make it clearer what I can and cannot use.

Comment: your while loop breaks after when it find duplicate 2's in `find_duplicates([1, 2, 2, 0]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code returns a duplicate *prematurely*; traversing the list, the function first finds `2` as a duplicate, return it, and halts the function immediately. But it has not seen the `0` at the end.

So, you need to let the function see the list all the way towards the end, looking for a negative number. If a negative number is found along the way, you can halt the function. If it does not see a negative number until the end, then let it return the duplicate value:

```py
def find_duplicates(ls):
    if not isinstance(ls, list): # check whether ls is a list
        return -1

    dup = 0
    seen = [] # list of numbers seen so far
    i = 0 # index

    while i < len(ls):
        if ls[i] < 1: # if a negative number is found, return -1
            return -1
        if ls[i] in seen and dup == 0:
            dup = ls[i]
        seen.append(ls[i])
        i += 1
    return dup

print(find_duplicates([1, 2, 2, 0])) # -1
print(find_duplicates([1, 1, 2, 2, 3])) # 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is beacause you are breaking while loop when find a duplicated. In that case, function is finding first the duplicated.

Try this:

```
def find_duplicates(ls):
    if type(ls) is not list:
        return -1
    duplicated = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(ls):
        if ls[i] < 1:
            return -1
        if ls.count(ls[i]) > 1 and duplicated == 0
            duplicated = ls[i]
        i += 1
    return duplicated
```

Comment: Just a note `break` is unreachable here. No need for is as you `return` from the function anyway.

Comment: I already updated... check again. If there are no duplicates, then returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your test case returns 2 because `2` stay at lower indexes comparing to `0`.

I would suggest to `sort` the list before moving on:

```py
def find_duplicates(ls):
    if type(ls) != list:
        return -1

    sorted_list = ls.sorted()           #Assign sorted `ls` to another variable, while keeping the order of `ls` intact
    non_dupe = []
    i = 0
    
    while i < len(ls):
        if ls[i] < 1:
            return -1
            break
        if ls.count(i) > 1:
            return i
            break
        else:
            non_dupe.append(i)
            i += 1
    
    if len(non_dupe) == len(ls):
        return 0
```

Another method I would recommend is using `set` - a built-in data type of Python. Maybe you should consider trying this approach later on when all test cases are passed. Have a look at this Tutorial for `set` usage: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp.

Comment: Sorting the list won't find the first duplicate, as you're rearranging the order. Order needs to stay intact to determine which element is first duplicated.

Comment: My bad, I missed that point. Thank you so much for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

You were very close.  Try this:

```
def find_duplicates(ls):
    if type(ls) != list:
        return -1   
    non_dupe = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(ls):
        if ls[i] < 1:
            return -1
        elif ls[i] in non_dupe:
            return ls[i]
        else:
            non_dupe.append(i)
        i += 1
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [1,2,2,0]

result = list(set(filter(lambda x: my_list.count(x) > 1 , my_list)))

# Result =>  [2]
```

I hope this solves your problem